# Installing new PHP version for MAMP on Mac

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mamp

I tried to install the PHP extension libraries for MongoDB, however updating the `php.ini` files caused some problems and caused the MySQL servers on my localhost to not start. I use MAMP, but when I start it now, Apache loads but MySQL doesnt and I can't load any web pages.

So I downloaded the same version of PHP from http://php-osx.liip.ch/ to reinstall PHP and I'm now trying to update the right files on my system so that this is the version that is used.

I've updated the path in the terminal (using `export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH`) and now get the newly installed version there when I run `php -v`.

But when I run phpinfo, I still get the old version. I still can't load any localhost web pages or phpMyAdmin.

Thanks very much for help figuring this out! I'm a front-end developer without a lot of backend experience.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to install PHP on a Mac is to use [Mac Ports](http://www.macports.org/).

This community make the repository up to date and give you the choice between PHP 5.3, 5.4 and even 5.5.

When you'll have `port` installed, install php5.4 (or another one) and pecl :

```
sudo port install php54 php54-pear
```

Then, use pear to add MongoDB support:

```
sudo pecl install mongo
```

Some links:

- [Installing Mac Ports](http://www.macports.org/install.php)
- [How to install MongoDB for PHP on Mac OS X](http://manas.tungare.name/blog/how-to-install-mongodb-for-php-on-mac-os-x/)

Comment: Thanks for the information about Mac Ports. I've already tried Homebrew and did the install that way but that didn't work either which is why I used the package at http://php-osx.liip.ch/